# Convert c calling function in assembly codes to assembly as well

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I am working on a C file with some mathematical functions such as `log` and `exp`. I 
compile the C file with GCC to generate assembly codes. Inside the assembly codes, whenever a `pow` function is used, I find that it will just call the C function. For instance,

```
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR 16[rbp]   
    call    log  
    addsd   xmm0, xmm0  
    call    exp  
    movsd   QWORD PTR -8[rbp], xmm0
```

I am wondering if it is possible to tell GCC so that instead of just calling the C function, it will also generate the assembly code for `log` and `exp`? In other words, is it possible to tell GCC to generate assembly codes that do not require any external function calling?

Thanks,

Comment: You just need to look at the source for libm.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?  I.e., are you just curious, or do you think you'll be able to hand-optimize the compiled assembly?

Comment: Its a research project that we worked on, the simulator only takes pure assembly codes, no function call is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load your program in GDB or another debugger, and set a breakpoint on the call, and then step into the `log` or `exp` function and when there, dump the disassembly of it (or copy & paste it if you're running an appropriate debugger).  You can do that even if you don't have source for the library functions.

Comment: Neat idea, but this isn't portable, is it?

Comment: Yeah this is a good idea. I used visual studio to do this, its very messy and difficult to track but at least it is doable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this can be done in a standard way.  You could, however, implement the functions yourself (or copy the code from existing libraries, such as libm (part of [libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)) as Paul R mentioned), and then, importantly, declare the function **[inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function)**.

Comment: Yep I looked up the flibm package and it does show the source code for various mathmatical functions.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you can copy paste the code from libm.

Try compiling with `-finline-functions` and `-finline-limit=n`
See [OptimizeOptions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for more information

Comment: @mathk Yeah I was thinking about that last night before I went to bed. It would have to be statically linked.